How to Change Language Without Redirecting Pages with Next.js?
I provide multi-language support to the Nextjs project using the next-i18next package. English and German languages.
There is a fixed menu named Home Page, Categories, Contact. The names of these menus need to be changed by changing the language with the help of a button.
i18n.changeLanguage('en'); With the method, the change is not reflected on the screen. State is not updated. I see that it has changed with console.log.
const { i18n } = useTranslation();
const router = useRouter();
function changeLanguage(language) {
  i18n.changeLanguage(language);
  router.push(router.asPath, undefined, { locale: language });
}

By using the method, it works and the state changes when the page is directed to /blog/en and blog/de.
Can't the language be changed without refreshing the page and redirecting (router.push())?
Am I using the wrong package?
